# Load file with unlimited time by javascript

Tags: javascript, load

I need to load a file (PHP) everysecond because the file which I load include a timer with information and "mysql_fetch_array" , when I load the file every 5 seconds the timer (11:10:50) become weird and the numbers interfere together .

I tried to load the file every 1 millisecond but session crahed !

```
setInterval(function() {$("#Timer").load("timer.php");}, 1);
```

Comment: 1ms is insane, forget it. You are better off querying once, then using that to sync a local timer. Also use getJSON, quicker than .load()

Comment: If I load it every 0.5s the session will crash again ?

Comment: If you are trying to DoS your own server, this is a great start at it!

Comment: even if you do it ever 1s, that's still an insane amount of stress to put on a server. Forget doing by interval and just keep a local timer runnin in JS and sync it ONCE with the server at the beginning, it can keep time on its own after that.

Comment: Loading anything on a short interval timer from a server over and over again is simply a flawed design.  You haven't really described the overall problem you are trying to solve so we can't really tell what the best alternative would be.  Right now this question is the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are describing a problem with your attempted solution rather than describing the actual problem you're trying to solve, thus we can't help you with a better solution that is different than what you are currently trying.